# Why did Rumpelstiltskin and Regina remain aware of their normal selves during the curse?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

Having completed the first season, it's evident that Rumpelstiltskin and Regina are aware of their former selves while living in Storeybrooke. Why is this? Would it be because they respectively created the curse and invoked it, or due to being powerfully magical?

Comment: The mad hatter/aka Jefferson seemed to have retained some memory as well.   I don't know if this was ever explained, beyond "they were magical beings", but I'd be curious if someone can answer it with more clarity.

Comment: Regina was immune to the memory loss because she cast the curse - not much point in doing something like that if you're going to forget you did it, evil people are not known to sacrifice power.  IIRC (it has been a while),   Rumple was immune because he made a deal with Regina that he would help her to get what she needed to *cast the curse* on the condition that he be spared from its effects himself.  (That was in one of the flashbacks in season 1, or possibly 2.)

Comment: @Steve-O That looks like answer material. Want to add an answer?